# Different delay on second menu click or close

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu, click, toggle

**Situation:** Wordpress theme mobile menu doesn't extend to the top. Since I have an image in the site header and it gets cut in half right now by the menu I would like to completely cover it by the menu when its open.

**The fix:** Change transparent-header class to white background on menu click.

**My problem:** The stock theme menu got an ease transition for closing the menu while my white background disappears nearly immediately. The timing when my white background color disappears is way to fast but the timing on opening the menu is good. So I need a different delay for closing. Do I need to go the if/else route here?

This is what I have right now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".mobile-menu").on("click", function () {
    $(".transparent-header").toggleClass("white", 1000);})
});
```

This is one of the experiments that didn't work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
if($(".mobile-menu").hasClass("opened")){ //open function
     $(".transparent-header").css("white", 1000);
}else{
     $(".transparent-header").css("transparent", 4000);
}
});
```

Solution: What works for me. I let other decide if this thread should be deleted. I would find it quite helpful.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".mobile-menu").on("click", function() {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("opened")) {
          $(".transparent-header").toggleClass("white", 1000);
         }
         else
         {
            $(".transparent-header").delay(480).queue(function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("white");
                next();})
         }
       
       })});
```